# Is it possible to access a drawable from a specific density in Android?

Tags: android, drawable

Depending on the situation of course, I normally have a drawable for each density my app supports and the right density drawable is used when I use an id reference of some drawable.

But I'm looking to access a drawable from a specific density (for example, ldpi) no matter the density running on the device. But I want this on a specific situation, not everywhere, that would defeat the purpose of having multiple drawables for each density.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know that it is possible or not but as a simple logic.

You just make a **copy of that ldpi drawable and name it mypic2 and keep it in ldpi folder**.

now from your xml or activity give the **reference of that new mypic2 at your specific situation**.

Comment: The drawable I need is already there, so I create a duplicate and increase the size of my app? That's exactly what I was trying to avoid...

Comment: yeh i know thats ur trying to minimize the memory usage..but will need to do some more learning for that..sorry right now i hv no other solution

Comment: I guess this is the only possible solution so I' marking it as accepted. If anyone else comes up with a better solution, I'll change it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I used to load a hdpi drawable from another app (works only with Android 4.0)

```
PackageInfo pi = packages.get(i);

ai = new AppListAdapter.AppItem();
try {
    Context otherAppCtx = getApplicationContext().createPackageContext(pi.applicationInfo.packageName, CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);

    ai.Icon = otherAppCtx.getResources().getDrawableForDensity(pi.applicationInfo.icon,  DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH);

} catch (Exception e) {
    ai.Icon = pi.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If it's one specific drawable, then just have it in the ldpi folder. The runtime will pick it up from there if it can't find it in any of the more appropriate density folders.

Comment: No, it can be any drawable from a predefined set (but it's a lot of drawables) and I have a drawable for each density available. I just need to access a specific density drawable on a specific situation.