# Application icon size issue below Android 4.0 : Google TV

Tags: android, user-interface, icons, google-tv

In my Google TV application, I am listing out other applications (their icon and package name) and when the user clicks on them, respective application will launch.

I noticed that, other applications icons are quite small compared to Google TV resolution.

Right now, both `width` and `height` of each icon is `wrap_content`.

If I make it hard coded, its looking blurry.

I am using the below code to get the icon:

```
Drawable icon = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(mContext.getPackageManager());
```

Anybody please help me out to solve this issue.

**Edit :**

Answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600740/getting-app-icon-in-android), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359583/get-drawable-for-density-for-api-level-15) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386040/retrieving-xhdpi-app-icons-from-packagemanager/18387344#18387344) are for version **4.0** and above.

I am in search for a solution from version **3.2** and above.

TIA.

Comment: How do you retrieve the application icons? Are you using ResolveInfo.LoadIcon?

Comment: I am using `Drawable icon = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(mContext
     .getPackageManager());`

Comment: Check out the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600740/getting-app-icon-in-android . Ignore the accepted answer.

Comment: @Paul-Jan Those answers r for Android 4.0 and above... I need for 3.2 and above.